# R script not launch histogramme from bash

Tags: python, r, bash, histogram, rscript

I have a histogram.R with chmod 755.
I want to display the histogram. 
From a R console (with removing the "#!/usr/bin/env Rscript") it's work but not when I execute the script from my shell.
Just by doing : ./histogram.R 
I have this for output :

```
 [1] 58384 67239 23702 32667 60158 21209 49167 33010 20278 46316 35619    NA
[13] 26647    NA 44791 21630 41907 58796 15578 56909 46550
```

This is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
contenuTotalFichier <- read.csv("./resources/dataset_train.20.csv")
colonne.Arithmancy <- contenuTotalFichier["Arithmancy"][,1]
print(colonne.Arithmancy)

hist(colonne.Arithmancy, col = grey(0.9), border = grey(0.2),
main = paste("Quel cours de Poudlard a une répartition des notes homogènes entre les quatres maisons
?"),
xlab = "effectifs en fonction des maisons",
ylab = "cours de Poudlard",
labels = TRUE, las = 1, ylim = c(0, 50))
```

Soluce find :
save graph as pdf and open it after with ggplot2 (example with generic data)

```
library(ggplot2)
data=data.frame(x=rnorm(100))
plot=qplot(x, data=data, geom="histogram") 
ggsave(plot,file="graph1.pdf")
system("open graph1.pdf")
```

Comment: Your script is putting the histogram in a device you cannot see.

Comment: Surround the call to `hist` with a redirect to a graphics device -- would you like to save the histogram as a png? then surround it with `png('file_name.png'); hist_call; dev.off()`

Comment: I use the soluce to save sur graph as pdf and open it after.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
contenuTotalFichier <- read.csv("./resources/dataset_train.20.csv")
colonne.Arithmancy <- contenuTotalFichier["Arithmancy"][,1]
print(colonne.Arithmancy)

x11() # if you're on linux; quartz() if macOS

hist(colonne.Arithmancy, col = grey(0.9), border = grey(0.2),
main = paste("Quel cours de Poudlard a une répartition des notes homogènes entre les quatres maisons
?"),
xlab = "effectifs en fonction des maisons",
ylab = "cours de Poudlard",
labels = TRUE, las = 1, ylim = c(0, 50))

invisible(readLines("stdin", n=1)) # Wait for ENTER so the chart stays up
dev.off() # close the X11 device
```

Do what Michael suggested if you want to make a file.

Comment: very nice solution!

Comment: I tried but not work... I use the soluce to save sur graph as pdf and open it after.